# CSS import aliases with Next.js

Tags: next.js, postcss, postcss-import

There are many solutions floating around regarding import aliases within JavaScript/TypeScript files using Next.js

Does anyone have a working example of something similar with CSS?

For example, I have an alias `@Styles` that I have in the `tsconfig.json` as

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "@/*": ["./src/*"],
  "@Components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
  "@Components": ["./src/components"],
  "@Icons/*": ["./src/components/Icons/*"],
  "@Icons": ["./src/components/Icons"],
  "@Images/*": ["./src/assets/images/*"],
  "@Images": ["./src/assets/images"],
  "@Styles/*": ["./src/assets/styles/*"],
  "@Styles": ["./src/assets/styles"]
}
```

In a CSS file, I try to do something like this `@import '@Styles/layout.css';`. This doesn't work.

`postcss.config.js` looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {
      root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      path: ['assets'],
      skipDuplicates: true
    },
    'postcss-nesting': {},
    'postcss-custom-media': {},
    'autoprefixer': {}
  }
};
```

Can someone help guide what am I missing to configure CSS postcss-import aliases? Is this possible with Next.js?

Answer (score 0):

Given the CSS import statement `@import '@Styles/layout.css';` the configuration below resolves to that CSS import:

```
//postcss.config.js
const path = require('path');


const aliasMapping = {
  '@Styles': (filename) => path.resolve(__dirname, `src/assets/styles/${filename}`),
  '@Images': (filename) => path.resolve(__dirname, `src/assets/images/${filename}`)
};


module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {
      root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      path: ['assets'],
      skipDuplicates: true,
      resolve: (id, basedir, importOptions) => {
        const [aliasName, filename] = id.split('/');
        return aliasMapping[aliasName](filename);
      }
    },
    'postcss-nesting': {},
    'postcss-custom-media': {},
    'autoprefixer': {}
  }
};
```

Now any CSS file can implement an import alias successfully. In the `aliasMapping` you just continue to add aliases as needed.